# How to enter a parameter for a HTTP GET request that doesn't have a name?

Tags: python, parameters, get, request

I'm using the *requests* module for python, and sending a GET request to a site as follows:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com", params={"search_query":"Hello World"}).text
```

Which just returns the HTML of the page on YouTube that searches for "Hello World", which is the parameter for a field with the name "search_query".

However, let's say that one parameter I want to input does not have a name on the site, but is still part of the form.

The site I'm talking about has the following code:

```
<input type="text" id="youtube-url" value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhBE" onclick="sALL(this)" autocomplete="off" style="width:466px;">
```

How would I go about sending a parameter to this specific input, considering it does not have a name?

Thanks

**EDIT:** The full HTML of the code:

[image]

Comment: If the input does not have a name, it is not submitted with the form. What does the javascript do? Maybe it uses `id`s as names?

Comment: I don't know much about Javascript, but it doesn't look like it uses the ids as names based on the site's HTML (http://www.youtube-mp3.org/)

Comment: Submit the form and look what happens in the Network tab of the inspector, you can see exactly what and how gets submitted.

Comment: I've looked there, but I'm still struggling with it: it's not clear to me how the site goes about submitting input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site doesn't do any normal submitting, everything is done via javascript.
When you push the button a GET request is sent like this:

```
"/a/pushItem/?item=" + escape(g("youtube-url").value)
   + "&el=na&bf=" + getBF()
   + "&r="+ (new Date()).getTime();
```

Then with the result of this, another is sent:

```
"/a/itemInfo/?video_id=" + video_id + "&ac=www&t=grp&r=" + a.getTime();
```

So in python you can try this:

```
import time

videoid = requests.get("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/pushItem/",
                 params={
                      "item": "your youtube video url",
                      "el": "na",
                      "bf": "false",
                      "r": int(time.time() * 1000000)   # JS timestamps are in microseconds
                 }).text


info = requests.get("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/",
                   params={
                       "video_id": videoid,
                       "ac": "www",
                       "t": "grp",
                       "r": int(time.time() * 1000000)
                   }).text
```

And then you'll have to parse the `info`, which isn't even JSON, but more javascript, and do whatever you want with that data.

You might have to deal with CAPTCHAs or conversion progress.

Comment: Just one question: what do you mean by "parse the info"

Comment: You'll get a string like this: `info = { "title" : "Developers", "image" : "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/KMU0tzLwhbE/default.jpg", "length" : "3", "status" : "serving", "progress_speed" : "", "progress" : "", "ads" : "", "pf" : "", "h" : "b89796b7f81990b00f3352c80227f6cb" };`, you'll have to extract the useful information from it.

Comment: Mainly the `h` bit. The download link is constructed with the video id you got earlier and that `h`.

Comment: Oh man, this is confusing: thanks though, I'll try to figure it out, and accept your answer when I do

Comment: Try to follow the javascript; go the Sources tab, select `client.js` and press the `{}` in the toolbar at the bottom to format it. `btnSubmitClick` is called when the button is pushed, `pushItem` sends the first request, `infoRehash` sends the second, `checkInfo` uses the data (builds the download link, for instance).